# Can I use SPDY with Unicorn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, spdy

I would like to use SPDY with my Rails application. I saw solutions how to setup [SPDY with NGINX + Passenger](http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/08/21/use-nginx-spdy-without-compiling-nginx-and-without-a-recent-openssl/) and also SPDY with Apache ([mod_spdy](https://code.google.com/p/mod-spdy/)).

Can I use SPDY with Unicorn and NGINX? How to configure it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nginx spdy module with Unicorn, there is nothing special about it. Just read the documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_spdy_module.html

Answer (score 0):

SPDY is only implemented on the web server, like NGINX or Apache. Unicorn has nothing to do with this. So you can patch up your web server and since Unicorn is an application server, it should have no effect on this.